# Transactions in unit of work pattern for EF core

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-core

I am using unit of work pattern for EF core database first approach in my application.
I have also implemented database transactions in unit of work class.
For e.g.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private myDBContext _dBContext;
    public IDatabaseTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        return new EntityDatabaseTransaction(_dBContext);
    }
}
```

Now I have handlers for different operations and each handler have dependency injection of unit of work. Inside handlers I am using transactions for DB operation.
For e.g.

```
public class Operation1Handler : BaseHandler
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public Operation1Handler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public override void Handle()
    {
        using(var _trans = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //some code
            _unitOfWork.Entity.SaveAsync();
            _trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this handler is getting called in a WebAPI method like

```
public void MyAPI()
{
    var handler = new Operation1Handler();
    handler.Handle();
}
```

So far this is working perfectly fine.
Now my problem is I have to call 2 different handlers in a WebAPI method which will do different DB operations. But I want all operations under both handlers to be transaction compliant i.e. if operation of handler 2 fails, operation of handler 1 should also rollback.

```
public void MyAPI()
{
    var handler = new Operation1Handler();
    handler.Handle();

    var handler2 = new Operation2Handler();
    handler2.Handle();
}
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: Don't begin the transaction by hand, the UnitOfWork should be the wrapper for it not a factory. Create a new UnitOfWork for each request to your Api -> The UnitOfWork begins the transaction -> Do your business stuff -> Dispose the UnitOfWork and commit the transaction. Besides, your `Operation1Handler` should not be aware of transaction handling, this is part of the infrastructure of your app.

Comment: Do not create a Rep/UoW, please read [Is the repository pattern useful with Entity Framework Core?](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you are configuring your DI, IUnitOfWork lifetime should be Scoped. Use AddScoped method instead of AddTransient

I agree with @Rabban comment. Don't begin transactions manually